XOR bytes in c#
I saw a neat way to swap 2 variables using XOR lately and decided to try that in c# with strings, and though I managed to do that I'm a little worried that I have to cast int into byte after the XOR operation. Here's the code:
var string1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello world1!");
var string2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello world2!");

for (var i = 0; i < string1.Length; i++)
{
    string1[i] = (byte)(string1[i] ^ string2[i]);
}

for (var i = 0; i < string2.Length; i++)
{
    string2[i] = (byte)(string1[i] ^ string2[i]);
}

for (var i = 0; i < string1.Length; i++)
{
    string1[i] = (byte)(string2[i] ^ string1[i]);
}

Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(string1));
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(string2));

Is there any better way of doing this? And while we are at it, what actually happens when you cast primitives in C#? Is there any new memory being allocated for it?

While it's an amusing trick, it has no practical use as doing the straight forward thing that you would do to swap two strings is much more efficient.

With the introduction of tuples in C#, the xor trick is actually no longer as neat as it used to be:
 var string1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello world1!");
 var string2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello world2!");

 (string1, string2) = (string2, string1);

 Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(string1));
 Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(string2));

The tuple syntax is explained here.

That's a cool way to solve this! And you don't even have to convert the string to a byte array in this case... Thanks for sharing!

That doesn't actually do the same thing: that swap the arrays rather than the array contents.
